# Issue with ruby savon jruby

Tags: ruby, jruby, savon

I'm trying to use the savon Gem, in order to interact with webServices.
So i installed it, and it seems that the installation was ok :

```
gem list savon
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
savon (1.2.0)
```

I can test it with the simple command :

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "savon"'
```

(I've no more error thanks to this tip http://wiki.mccune.org.uk/index.php/Backtrack)

The issue occurs when i want to use a .rb script that require savon :

```
jruby -S buby -i -B /pentest/web/burpsuite/burpsuite_v1.4.01.jar -r /home/fred/soapAtk2.rb 

/usr/lib/jruby//lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:75 warning: already initialized constant StartBurp
Your JRE appears to be OpenJDK. 
Burp has not been fully tested on this platform and you may experience problems.
Loading: "/home/fred/soapAtk2.rb"

/usr/lib/jruby//lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in **`require': no such file to load -- savon** (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/jruby//lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/fred/soapAtk2.rb:3
    from /home/fred/soapAtk2.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/jruby//lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buby-1.3.1-java/bin/buby:63
    from /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buby-1.3.1-java/bin/buby:63:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buby-1.3.1-java/bin/buby:63
    from /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buby-1.3.1-java/bin/buby:19:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/jruby/bin/buby:19
```

It seems there is a issue of environment, but i cannot figure out how to solve it :-/

```
ruby -r rubygems -e "p Gem.path"

["/root/.gem/ruby/1.9.2", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2"]

# gem content savon

/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/savon-1.2.0/.gitignore

/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/savon-1.2.0/.rspe
...
...
```

Others info

```
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [x86_64-linux]
# gem -v
1.3.7
```

Has anybody got the same issue (i run backtrack5 last release)

Thanks'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two rubies, the system one (1.9.2dev), and jruby.  When you are running `ruby` or `gem`, it picks up the system ruby, whereas the `jruby -S buby` command picks up jruby.

If you run:

```
jruby -rubygems -e 'require "savon"'
```

this will more than likely fail.

To install savon on the jruby instance, run:

```
jruby -S gem install savon
```

This should fix the issue.